# How to get radicals in R?

Tags: r, math, sqrt

If I have a number like 3.464102 (which is 2*sqrt(3)), how can I get R to tell me that? For example output might look like:

```
toRad(3.464102)
>> multiple: 2, root: 2, of: 3
```

This would be very useful. Any ideas?

Comment: is this possible?  irrational numbers go on forever, so how could you be sure a number is actually a number so to speak

Comment: Since there is no easy mathematical solution for this, it seems like it would require a script to try all of the possibilities. Also a fuzzing factor would be needed since irrational numbers cannot be input exactly, so the script would need to work with inexact results.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it could have an epsilon parameter to specify the precision, and the result could be a list of candidate radical expressions, or maybe the 'most reduced' one.

Comment: Looks like the `identify` function in Python does something similar to what I'm asking for in R. http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/mpmath/identification.html

Comment: It's really going to depend on what possibilities you may encounter.  If it's always `a*b^{1/n}`, then you could just take higher and higher powers and see if the result is close enough to an integer.  If constants like `π` and `e` can be used, that add another thing to check.  If addition and subtraction are allowed, that makes it significantly more complicated.

Comment: I don't see how this would be "very useful" for practical purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `primeFactors` function from the `numbers` library I wrote two little functions:

```
library(numbers)

f <- function(x,n)
{
  p <- primeFactors(round(x^n))
  q <- unique(p)
  m <- sapply(q,function(q){sum(p==q)})

  a <- prod(q^(m%/%n))
  b <- prod(q^(m%%n))
  c <- x-a*b^(1/n)

  return(c(a,b,c))
}

g <- function(x,n.max)
{
  A <- sapply(1:n.max,function(n){f(x,n)})
  i <- which.min(abs(A[3,]))

  return(c(A[1,i],A[2,i],i,A[3,i]))
}
```

`f` tries to decompose `x` as `a*b^(1/n)+c` such that `a` and `b` are integers and `abs(c)` is as small as possible.
`g` calls `f` for each value of `n` up to a bound `n.max` and picks the best choice.

Without the upper bound `n.max` any number `x` can be decomposed arbitrarily accurate. The error of the decomposition
`a*b^(1/n)` comes from the fractional digits of `x^n` and these are bounded by 1 whereas the integer part grows to infinity as `n` increases.

```
> g(3.464102,8)
[1] 2.000000e+00 3.000000e+00 2.000000e+00 3.848622e-07
> g(3.464102,12)
[1]  1.000000e+00  2.985988e+06  1.200000e+01 -1.844391e-09
> g(2*sqrt(3),12)
[1] 2 3 2 0
> g(123.45,5)
[1] 1.000000e+00 2.867183e+10 5.000000e+00 3.991403e-10
> g(pi,30)
[1] 1.000000e+00 2.614245e+14 2.900000e+01 0.000000e+00
>
```